# opencart import users from excel

Tags: php, mysql, excel, opencart

I have an opencart webpage and I need to import about 5000 of new user from excel. The problem is opencart stores users passwords as encrypted, but in my excel file they are as text.

any help please.

Comment: See https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/user.php#L37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of hours I solved the problem.
I am sharing the method for the beginers like me;)

open new text file and put following code then save as encryp.php and open it from your browser...

```
    <?php
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "your db user name"); //root for loacaldb
define("DB_PASS", "your db user pass"); //leave empty for local db
define("DB_NAME","your db name");
define("TBL_USERS", "table name"); 
define("FLD_USER", "email");
define("FLD_PASS", "password");

set_magic_quotes_runtime(0);
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$q = "SELECT ".FLD_PASS.",".FLD_USER." FROM ".TBL_USERS."";
$result = mysql_query($q, $connection);
$total=0;
$enc=0;
$doencrypt=false;
if(@$_REQUEST["do"]=="encrypt")
 $doencrypt=true;
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 if($doencrypt)
 {
  $total++;
  if(!encrypted($data[0]))
  {
   $q="UPDATE ".TBL_USERS." SET ".FLD_PASS."='".md5($data[0])."' where ".FLD_USER."='".
   str_replace("'","''",$data[1])."'";
   mysql_query($q, $connection);
  }
  $enc++;
 }
 else
 {
  $total++;
  if(encrypted($data[0]))
   $enc++;
 }
} function encrypted($str)
{
 if(strlen($str)!=32)
  return false;
 for($i=0;$i<32;$i++)
   if((ord($str[$i])<ord('0') || ord($str[$i])>ord('9')) && (ord($str[$i])<ord('a') 
     || ord($str[$i])>ord('f')))
   return false;
 return true;
}
?>
<html>
<head><title>Encrypt passwords</title></head>
<body>
Total passwords in the table - <?php echo $total; ?><br>
<?php if($enc==$total && $total>0) { ?>
All passwords are encrypted.
<?php } else if($total>0) { ?>
Unencrypted - <?php echo $total-$enc; ?><br><br>
Click "GO" to encrypt <?php echo $total-$enc; ?> passwords.<br>
WARNING! There will be no way to decipher the passwords.<br>
<input type=button value="GO" onclick="window.location='encrypt.php?do=encrypt';">
<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Now after updating the passwords which i have done from another db, not opencart. do you have the script of inserting the records to opencart?

Answer (score 2):

Before inserting change password as follows:

```
 $user_password = 'password'; // replace with the user password
 $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, 9);
 $password = sha1($salt . sha1($salt . sha1($user_password)));
```

Insert this `$password` into database table as the user password and also insert `$salt` in salt field.

Have a nice day!!

Comment: Yes, this is correct approach, though the OpenCart's password hashing is nice example of *security through obscurity* :-) **Anyway, do not forget to insert both `$salt` and `$password` to the database!** Otherwise nobody would be able to log in even with correct password used. If You are not sure about this at all, You could also use `catalog/model/account/customer.php::addCustomer()` method to do the job for You but You would have to make sure first that the given array contains the exact indexes that are then used in this model's method.

Comment: @shadyyx thanks a lot. I forgot to mention inserting the `salt` field.

Comment: First of all I am really pleasured for your helps. But I am new on php I could not understand this code. I uploaded my user table from excel with their password but I need to encrypt them. There are about 5000 user. What should I do

Comment: did you get the user passwords extracted from excel? If yes, encrypt the passwords as shown above and update both `salt` and `password` for the users.

Comment: No all fields are in same sheet,

Comment: you said you've imported the user data into the database table, right? The encrypt the passwords as shown above and update both salt and password for the users.

Comment: Yes I import to database, Where shall I run the above code and is it update all passwords...

Comment: fetch each user password and assign it to `$user_password`. Run the next 2 line of code also. update the database fields `password` and `salt` with `$salt` and `$password`. That's all!